# mongodb - different keyfiles for different replica sets?

Tags: replication, mongodb, sharding

I am building a cluster using mongodb (3.4). Can I use separate keyfiles for my configuration replica set and my shard replica sets? Judging by the documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/), it *seems* possible but I'm not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyfile is used to secure intra-cluster communication, so all components of a sharded cluster (`mongod` and `mongos`) must use the same keyfile.

The documentation you referenced is for a single replica set deployment. For a sharded cluster see: [Enforce Keyfile Access Control in Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-sharded-cluster/).

Comment: Excellent, thanks Stennie, I've been reading your other mongodb answers for the last few days straight :)

Comment: @mils Great! Glad the answers have been helpful :)

Comment: I'm down to the last step of setting up my cluster - selecting a shard key :| I'm terrified of one-way operations though, so if I could pick your juicy brain one more time I would really appreciate it. Question is on SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150693/mongodb-shard-key-compound-vs-hash)